# Servlet doesn't called

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have simple java web application.

There is index.html file with link that follow to path "test/aaa"

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="test/aaa"> click </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>web.Servlet1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>web.Servlet2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>       

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/haha/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

So path "test/aaa" lead to servlet web.Servlet1

```
package web;


import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet { 

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {                     

        System.out.println("1");

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");      
        view.forward(request, response);

        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
```

Servlet1 just lead to test.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>        
        <img src="haha/bbb">        
    </body>
</html>
```

test.jsp just display "Hello World!" and an image that "locate" at path "haha/bbb"

In web.xml it is set that path "haha/bbb" lead to servlet web.Servlet2 which generate and return simple image

```
package web;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet { 

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {                     

        System.out.println("3");

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(256, 256,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D imageGraphics = image.createGraphics();
        imageGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        imageGraphics.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200);        

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();

        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setContentLength(imageInByte.length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(imageInByte);  

        System.out.println("4");
    }
}
```

I was expect to see an image in browser and this output in console:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Instead I don't see image in browser and in console I see this:

```
1
2
1
2
```

Moreover if I manualy go to path "haha/bbb" in browser I get image and "34" in console

Can someone expain why web.Servlet1 called 2 times and web.Servlet2 not called at all?

Comment: try `<img src="./haha/bbb">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that when you call in `Servlet1`

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");      
view.forward(request, response);
```

your URL doesn't change, so it still is

```
server/YourProject/test/aaa
```

This means that when browser loaded code generated by `test.jsp` including

```
<img src="haha/bbb">
```

this path will be referring to

```
server/YourProject/test/haha/bbb
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
since this part is location of `aaa`, `haha/bbb` will be simply added to it.
```

(and because of `/test/*` mapping, Servlet1 will need to handle this call, which explains additional `1 2` output in console)

not to

```
server/YourProject/haha/bbb
```

To solve this problem don't use relative path, but full path to resource. You can create it with little help of EL

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/haha/bbb">
```

where `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/` returns your `server/projectName`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should very carefully use relative URLs in JSP/Servlets.

The issue is that servlet1 is serving URL <context_path>/test/aaa from where you make internal redirect to test.jsp.

test.jsp is handled in body of servlet1 and in context of request to servlet1 (GET /<context_path>/test/aaa). Browser sees relative url:

```
<img src="haha/bbb">
```

and expands it to /<context_path>/test/aaa/haha/bbb. Then browser make GET /<context_path>/test/aaa/haha/bbb and receives 404 Not Found.

So to fix your code replace

```
<img src="haha/bbb">
```

with

```
<img src="/haha/bbb">
```

or better -- enable taglib url and print:

```
<img src="<c:url value='/haha/bbb' />" >
```

Using taglibs for making URLs is much safer and easier than dealing with ContextPath

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative URLs.  Absent a `<base>` element to direct otherwise, the client browser resolves them against the request URL, which contains no information about any internal processing on the server side.

Thus, if the client requests URL `http://test/aaa`, and the HTML it receives back contains an element `<img src="haha/bbb">`, it resolves the image source URL against the request URL to get `http://test/haha/bbb`.  This URL is mapped to servlet1 (hence the second `1`, `2` in your console output), but servlet1 does not provide an image so none is displayed.

The easiest fix from where you now are would be for the JSP to include an appropriate `<base>` element in the `<head>` of the page it returns.  Alternatively, you could specify an absolute source URL, or at least an URL relative to the document root (`/haha/bbb`) or relative to the context root.